# Why do I still have duplicate rows in my table?

Tags: mysql, indexing, duplicates

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate rows of my table with more than 7 millions of rows.

To do this, I used this command to add a Index:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE DOBR ADD UNIQUE INDEX IDOBITO (PK1, DATEOC, DATENS, IDMUNRE, IDMUNOC, DATEINS);
```

I verified the duplicate rows using the following select:

```
select PK1, count(*) from DOBR group by PK1, DATEOC, DATENS, IDMUNRE, IDMUNOC, DATEINS having count(*) > 1
```

Before I have added the index, I used to have about to 17 thousand duplicate rows, but now I still have 187 duplicate rows. Why? They aren't supposed to be eliminated when I added the index?

Comment: Are you sure your `ALTER TABLE` statement succeeded? You are using the reserved word `INDEX` as the name of your index, which results in a syntax error.

Comment: I used INDEX IDOBITO. I put INDEX to hide the real name that I used.

That was a typo.